# How to control coordinates System of JAVAFX?

Tags: java, javafx, line, coordinates

```
public class FlowController implements Initializable{

    private Node targetNodeItem;
    private Group flowGroup;
    private Line flowLine;

    private double startX;
    private double startY;

    final ObjectProperty<Point2D> mousePoint = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
    final ObjectProperty<Point2D> drawStartPoint = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
    private Point2D drawPoint;

    public FlowController(){
        super();
    }

    public FlowController(Node nodeItem){

        nodeItem.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                moveNode(event);
            }
        });
        nodeItem.setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                moveNode(event);
            }
        });
        nodeItem.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                moveNode(event);
            }
        });

        nodeItem.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                moveNode(event);
            }
        });
    }

    @FXML
    public void moveNode(MouseEvent event){

        String eType = event.getEventType().getName();
        flowGroup = (Group)((Node)event.getTarget()).getParent();

        if( flowGroup == null ) {
            return;
        }

        if("MOUSE_PRESSED".equals(eType)) {
            targetNodeItem = (Node)event.getTarget();
            mousePoint.set(new Point2D(event.getSceneX(), event.getSceneY()));
        }

        if("MOUSE_DRAGGED".equals(eType)) {
            double targetX = event.getSceneX() - mousePoint.get().getX();
            double targetY = event.getSceneY() - mousePoint.get().getY();
            targetNodeItem.setLayoutX(targetNodeItem.getLayoutX()+targetX);
            targetNodeItem.setLayoutY(targetNodeItem.getLayoutY()+targetY);
            mousePoint.set(new Point2D(event.getSceneX(), event.getSceneY()));
        }

        if("MOUSE_CLICKED".equals(eType)) {
                if (event instanceof MouseEvent) {
                MouseEvent mouseEvent = (MouseEvent) event;
                if (MouseButton.SECONDARY == mouseEvent.getButton()) {
                    contextMenu(event);
                }
            }
        }

        if ("MOUSE_RELEASED".equals(eType)) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    private void contextMenu(final MouseEvent mouseEvent){

        final ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();

        targetNodeItem = (Node) mouseEvent.getTarget();
        targetNodeItem.setOnContextMenuRequested(new EventHandler<ContextMenuEvent>(){
            @Override
            public void handle(ContextMenuEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                MenuItem item1 = new MenuItem("Flowline");
                contextMenu.getItems().addAll(item1);
                contextMenu.show(targetNodeItem, mouseEvent.getScreenX()+20, mouseEvent.getScreenY());
                item1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent> () {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                        drawLine();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    @FXML
    public void drawLine(){

        flowLine = new Line();
        flowLine.setStrokeWidth(3);
        flowLine.setStroke(Color.RED);
        flowGroup.getChildren().add(flowLine);
        flowGroup.autosize();

        targetNodeItem.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent mEvent) {
                drawPoint = new Point2D(mEvent.getSceneX(), mEvent.getSceneY());
                startX = drawPoint.getX();
                startY = drawPoint.getY();
            }           
        });

        targetNodeItem.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent mEvent) {
                flowLine.setStartX(startX);
                flowLine.setStartY(startY);
                flowLine.setEndX(mEvent.getSceneX());
                flowLine.setEndY(mEvent.getSceneY());       
            }
        });
    }
}
```

`targetNodeItem` is the node.

I want to drag from that node and generate the `flowLine`, but the `coordinates of flowLine` which is generated as an [image](http://2url.kr/2lfjlsfa) is incorrect.

For reference [youtube](http://youtu.be/iZOL0Fs-umk)

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue may stem from screen DPI.

Check your screen DPI with this:

javafx.stage.Screen.getPrimary().getDpi();

100% DPI is 96, if your DPI is higher than this you'll need to scale the coordinates based on the current screen DPI.

This reference may help:
http://news.kynosarges.org/2013/08/09/javafx-dpi-scaling/

Comment: thanks nejinx.. my dpi is 120 (125%). so I changed my window dpi 96(100%).
but it doesn't work.. T.T

Comment: After changing the DPI to 96, did you remove the mouse adjustments to the coordinates you made above? e.g. replace double targetX = event.getSceneX() - mousePoint.get().getX(); with targetX = event.getSceneX()

Comment: Sorry for that I cant vote this up. My reputaion is just 1. :(